# Error using Thread.start() with Python3.9 and Gevent worker class

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gevent, python-3.9, greenlets

We have a Flask App which extensively uses threading.Thread class to spawn threads for Async API requests.
Sample flask app that imitates our application is as below.

```
from flask import Flask import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/count') def count():
    def do_work():
        for i in range(5):
            print(f'Processing item {i}')
            # Perform your work here

    # Create and start a new thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=do_work)
    thread.start()

    return 'Work started in a separate thread!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Running this Flask App(Flask-1.1.2) using Gunicorn(gunicorn-20.0.4) and Gevent worker class(gevent-21.1.2 and greenlet-0.4.17) on Python3.7.7 works fine.
But upgrading to Python3.9, the same code base has issue around starting threads (Thread.start()). Below is the stack trace when it fails.

```
thread.start()
 File “/var/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py”, line 899, in start
  _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
 File “/var/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent-21.1.2-py3.9-freebsd-11.4-RELEASE-amd64.egg/gevent/thread.py”, line 82, in start_new_thread
  greenlet = Greenlet.spawn(function, *args)
 File “src/gevent/greenlet.py”, line 687, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.spawn
AttributeError: type object ‘method’ has no attribute ‘start’
```

Tried upgrading gevent-21.1.2 and greenlet-0.4.17 to next latest versions to see if that solves the problem. But the issue remains the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.